# How to add .mp3 or .wav file to C program in Windows (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have made a game, something like pacman, and i want to add sound. It is small file. 
How to do that? Try to avoid making functions. Is there something included in libraries like (windows.h) or something else? Thanks.
I have tried to write it like this, but it`s not working:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    PlaySound("c:\\bird.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is that the correct path and filename?

Comment: I am getting this error: Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PlaySoundW@12 referenced in function _main C:\Users\Korisnik\bla\bla\bla.obj

Comment: Perform some basic research perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unresolved external is Winmm.dll, where the function is located

to solve this problem add `#pragma comment(lib,"Winmm.lib")` to the code.
And don't forget to encapsulate the text while calling the function like this :
`PlaySound(TEXT("bird.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);` .
Then go to Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, press Edit to Add winmm.lib and apply the changes.

**(To make strings portable between unicode and non-unicode, use the TEXT() macro to automatically define a string as being unicode or not)**

EDIT : The sound file should be in the same folder of the executable or in the Windows Directory.

Comment: I am very sorry to ask you, but, can you tell me how to do that? I am beginner in C programming.

Comment: That's very simple just add `#pragma comment(lib,"Winmm.dll")` after the `#include`'s. And instead of `PlaySound("c:\\bird.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);`, put this `PlaySound(TEXT("c:\bird.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);`

Comment: Go to Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, press <Edit> and Add winmm.lib and apply the changes.
also edit the `winmm.dll` and make it `winmm.lib`

Comment: Also I realized a problem right now, the file should be a system sound or in the same directory of the executable file. So, `PlaySound(TEXT("bird.wav"),NULL,SND_ASYNC);` and put the bird.wav sound in the same folder with the executable (while debugging copy the sound file to bin/Debug folder)
for more info on how to make the sound file as a resource file see [PlaySound Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Better yet, embed the WAV file as a resource and then play it by passing the `SND_RESOURCE` flag to the `PlaySound` function. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743679.aspx)